# Does Swift Package not support Xib files

Tags: swift, package, swift-package-manager

I am currently trying to add a xib file for a custom popup to my Swift Package. However, it won't says:

'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/--/testingSDK.app> (loaded)' with name 'consentViewModal''

I have seen around people discussing that Swift Packages doesn't support anything but source code and I was wondering if this was still true. Below is the code that we are using to instantiate the custom view.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "consentViewModal", bundle: Bundle(for: consentViewModal.classForCoder()))

guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else {
    fatalError("Failed to instantiate nib \(nib)")
}
    
self.addSubview(view)
view.frame = self.bounds
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
```

Comment: It depends on the Swift version 5.3. See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/add-resources-to-swift-packages/

Comment: @Larme I have added it to my package directory but it is still kicking back an error. As you can see in the error log it seems like even though it is calling my Swift package bundle it is still trying to load it from the main app bundle

Answer (score 2):

1. When the `.xib` is inside of a Swift Package, you must use `Bundle.module`

   The "module" bundle "Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module."

   For example:

   ```
   let loadedNib = Bundle.module.loadNibNamed(String(describing: type(of: self)), owner: self, options: nil)

   guard let contentView = loadedNib?.first as? UIView else {
      return nil
   }
   ```

2. Also, ensure that within the `.xib` itself, that you update the "module" name to be that of your Swift Package on the right hand side "Identity Inspector". It should **not** say "None" as shown below:

   [image]

3. Also, although I'm not sure if necessary, place the `.xib` file within the "Resources" folder under the root directory of your target folder.